# Populate ListBox after clicking Submit button

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to populate a listbox after inputting text into a text box and clicking Submit. Seems simple I know, but I'm new to Data Binding and WPF...

Here's my code so far... I don't know if the XAML is correct, and of course I have nothing in the event code behind... any help would be appreciated.

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=accountaddTextBox, Path=SelectedItem.Content, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"  Height="164" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12" Name="accountListBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="161" />
```

Code behind:

```
private void okBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: What you want to populate your `listbox` with?

Comment: Oh sorry, I want to enter text into a text box and have the user hit Submit and it populates the listbox.

Comment: populate list box with content of textbox?

Comment: Yes. I want to populate the listbox with the contents of a text box. The listbox must save and show whatever a user adds via that textbox.

Comment: If you're new to data binding you should read [the overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current binding is telling the `ListBox` to find an object named `accountaddTextBox`, and bind to its `SelectedItem.Content`. I am assuming that `accountaddTextBox` is a `TextBox`, and `SelectedItem` is not a valid property on `TextBox`, so your binding is invalid.

It would be far better to bind your ListBox to an `ObservableCollection<string>` that is located in your code-behind or `ViewModel`, and have your button add a new object to that collection. Since it is an `ObservableCollection`, the UI will automatically update

For example,

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeObservableCollection}" />

private void okBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SomeObservableCollection.Add(accountaddTextBox.Text);
}
```

Comment: technically, the `SelectedItem.Content` property could exist at *runtime*, since SelectedItem is just an object...

Comment: @JohnGardner Not if `accountaddTextBox` is a `TextBox`..... `TextBoxes` don't have a `SelectedItem` property

Comment: ah, true that.  i would have never expected something bound to selecteditem to be a textbox in the first place... :)